# Como agrego dos columnas a este codigo?

Tags: java, android, array, apache

buenos dias llevo ya un buen rato intentando agregar dos columnas en el segundo array y no se como hacerlo. He buscado por internet y no he encontrado gran cosa

```java
public class Ej2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] datos = new int[7][5];
        System.out.println("Array inicial");
        for (int i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < datos[i].length; j++) {
                datos[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            }
            System.out.println("" + Arrays.toString(datos[i]));
        }
        int[][] datos2 = Arrays.copyOf(datos, datos.length);

        System.out.println("Array igual pero con dos columnas añadidas: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < datos.length; j++) {

            }
            System.out.println("" + Arrays.toString(datos2[i]));
        }

       

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

en Java no se puede aumentar el tamaño del array, pero si se puede reservar memoria para un nuevo bloque de memoria en la cual copiamos los elementos del bloque antiguo en el bloque nuevo y para no estar haciendo este mismo procedimiento cada vez que se quiera insertar un nuevo elemento al array, lo hacemos cuando la cantidad de elementos supere la capacidad máxima del array.

Una solución que se me ocurre para tu caso es quitar el Arrays.copyOf() ya que este va establecer las dimensiones de tu anterior array y haría algo así:

```
int[][] aux = new int[tamaño que quiera][tamaño que quiera];
for (int i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < datos.length; j++) {
       aux[i][j] = datos[i][j];
    }
}
```

Espero que le sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar el bucle que imprime la matriz  **datos2**  para copiar los datos de la matriz  **datos** y a su vez completar los datos de las 2 nuevas columnas que agregas como bien te han mencionado una vez declarado la longitud de un array este no puede aumentar o disminuir, pero eso no implica que otro array pueda contener los datos de otro y adicionalmente aumentar su longitud, asi evitarias el uso de **Arrays.copyOf()** el cual realiza una copia de un array a otro. datos y longitud

Fuente:[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int%5B%5D,%20int))

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] datos = new int[7][5];
    System.out.println("Array inicial");
    for (int i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < datos[i].length; j++) {
            datos[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        }
        System.out.println("" + Arrays.toString(datos[i]));
    }
    int nuevaColumna=(datos[0].length)+2;
    int [][] datos2=new int[7][nuevaColumna];

    System.out.println("\nArray igual pero con dos columnas añadidas: \n");

    for (int i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < datos[i].length; j++) {
            //Llenamos las 2 nuevas columnas
             datos2[i][j+2]=(int) (Math.random() * 10);
           //copiamos los valores de datos a datos2
             datos2[i][j]=datos[i][j];

        }
        System.out.println("" + Arrays.toString(datos2[i]));
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]